# animation backgroundcolor fade out doesn't work

Tags: jquery

I couldn't make this backgroundcolor fade out work

```
$("#x").css("background-color", "#00FF00")
$("#x").animate({ backgroundColor: '#000000' }, 2000)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bf2vwba7/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you used it is part of `jquery-ui` [Color Animation](http://jqueryui.com/animate/). You can include it to your project:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p0w2apwe/)

Comment: your fiddle example is different then mine, first it shoud be white in default. then green to white fade out.

Comment: still first state is green not white.

Comment: I know what I am asking looks like I am noob but when you try you will see its not working as I requested. I feel like its a bug.

Comment: And another one starting with one second delay [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wmh93cv1/)

Comment: yes, I tried exactly this before but couldn't make it work. so I will check libraries maybe somehow they doesn't work. http://jsfiddle.net/0wja9s36/

Comment: In your fiddle you didn't include jquery-ui. You can include it just checking the checkbox jQuery UI 1.10.3 :)

Comment: I deliberately didnt include to simulate my condition in my project. some how jquery-ui doesn't work in my project, can't find the reason. but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you do this with CSS transitions:

```
#x
{
    -webkit-transition: background-color 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: background-color 2s;  
}
```

Then merely set the CSS or toggle a class without worrying about the animation:

```
$("#x").css("background-color", "#000000");
$("#x").css("background-color", "#00FF00");
```

I would probably prefer to toggle a class if it were me and the context was right for it:

**CSS:**

```
#x
{
    -webkit-transition: background-color 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: background-color 2s;  
    background-color: #00FF00;
}

#x.black
{
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$('#x').toggleClass('black');
```

Here you've got a nice separation of functionality and style.

Transitions *can* have certain performance benefits, but be sure to check compatibility if you choose this route:

http://caniuse.com/#search=transitions